# Disable product from magento search

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

I would like to disable the product only from search. The product should be enabled and can be seen on the category page and everywhere except on the search page.

Comment: assign product only for catalog.

Comment: Disabled or Hide?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Should not appear thats all. Simply hide.

Comment: @RamaChandranM Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal provided good  ans :)

Answer (score 1):

In the **Admin Dashboard**,try to redirect to **Products** -> **Catalog** -> **Choose Edit which Product that you want to disable in search**.

Scroll down, find the **Visibility** label. Choose `Catalog` and Save.
[image]

After that, don't forget to reindex(**System** -> **Tool** -> **Index Management**). Your product will not appear in search only.

Comment: Thanks Nero. I think someone played with attribute sets and moved it to irrelevant section.

Answer (score 0):

Magento, go to **Catalog menu>Manage Products** and select the product that you want to edit from the table with the existing products in your catalog. On the page with the general settings of that product (displayed by clicking on the General button on the left) find the drop-down menu labeled **Visibility** and set it to **Catalog**. Then click on the Save or on the **Save and Continue** Edit button. In this way the product will be visible in the catalog on the frontend, but **it will not be shown in search results.**

Comment: Sorry but couldn't find the visibility option in product page. Im using 2.1.7

Comment: Thanks. Steps changed but things are same. Can't vote up as im new and have 1 reputation

Comment: After saving the product, please execute `index:reindex` command @AbhinavKumar